# Any idea why my self-answer might have been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, specific-answer

I will appreciate if someone can provide their guess for why [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4623635/18573) to my own question is getting downvoted.

To summarize, the question is:

> Is there a `Map<K1, K2, V>` implemented in Java where the retrieval can be performed with either of two different types, like a primary key and alternate key?

My answer:

> There isn't such a popular map implementation.

Comment: Well, it *doesn't answer the question* for starters...

Comment: Terrible "answer", accepted for the sake of it, with lots of reasonable ones available... -1

Comment: The answer is *"I need to accept some answer. The consensus seems to be that no such exists out there but is a useful concept."* ... The first sentence is already a pretty good indication you should have stopped right there. And the second sentence doesn't add a whole lot either. It's a bad answer.

Comment: [Nope.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4623635/18573)

Comment: Thank you for additional downvotes. I did get several comments asking me to improve my accept rate, which is why I accepted it. But I would argue that it *does* answer the question. The question "is there any...?" the answer is "no"

Comment: @HemalPandya There no longer is such a thing as accept rate. And such comments are easily ignored (and should really be flagged). Don't ever feel pushed into accepting anything.

Answer (score 15):

Because it isn't really an answer and is at best a comment on your question.

Why not just leave your question open? We [no longer show your accept rate publicly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654), so there is no impetus to accept a non-answer if none exist.

<sub>(Rereading your question, you should encourage [Rekin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311103/any-implementation-of-mapk1-k2-v-i-e-two-keys/4623635#comment5085100_4623635) to post their comment as an answer. A composite key would likely be best made into its own class.)</sub>

Comment: It *is* an answer -- for example, to the question "is there anything that travels faster then light"? The answer is "no".

Comment: @Hemal The strictly correct answer to that is actually "not to our knowledge" :)

Comment: @Hermal: considering you were given 2 answers to your question, you have no leg to stand on. If you don't *like* those answers, that is fine, but they were answers that would work. (I downvoted the one that did not actually work)

Comment: @sixlettervariables which answer is correct? Aren't they all describing a complex key situation instead of alternate key that I am asking for?